# Resize Google marker cluster map on Bootstrap tab click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, markerclusterer

I've tried a couple different responses from here, all without success.

From the title you can guess when the Bootstrap tab is opened the map needs to be resized since the map when it loads is 0x0, I can't figure out how to make this works.

My current attempt is included below, but getting no results.

```html
<div id="content">
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#detail" data-toggle="tab">Hotspot Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="#table" data-toggle="tab">Recent Sightings Table</a></li>
     <li><a href="#nearby" data-toggle="tab">Nearby Hotspots</a></li>
     <li><a href="#plan" data-toggle="tab">Weather Forecast</a></li>
    <li style='padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px;'><div id='loadgif'><img src='/images/36.gif'/> Loading Hotspot Data</div></li>

</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="detail">
//some info is displayed here
 </div>

// this starts the second tab
<div class="tab-pane" id="nearby">
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r287/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer';
  if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
    script += '_compiled';
  }
  script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
  document.write(script);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); //these come from some php variables
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var tab = jQuery('.tabs')[1]
            jQuery(tab).one('click', function(){
              google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
              map.setCenter(center)
            });


var hotspots = [
['ASU Research Park', 33.3428, -111.8975, '2', '204', '28', 'Maricopa', 'Arizona', 'L283889'], 
['Chaparral Park', 33.5110032, -111.906631, '7', '1', '1', 'Maricopa', 'Arizona', 'L357429']]
// more results are here
    var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < hotspots.length; i++) {
            var imageUrl = '/images/green.png';
            var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,new google.maps.Size(32, 32));
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(hotspots[i][1],hotspots[i][2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                icon: markerImage,
                title: hotspots[i][0],
                  map: map
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });
            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent('some html here');
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

            })(marker, i));  
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<div id='map-container'><div id='map'></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you do it without  the bootstrap tabs first. Then if all is working incorporate bootstrap tabs

Comment: it works without the tabs...that was my first step..got it working wihtout then added it to a tab, but having this issue...

Comment: There are rules in Google Map that when you didn't follow may break or cause  to not show the map in your page. see this to see common pitfalls. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21PDd17dnnI

Comment: i misspoke, its not that nothing shows, its that the map size is off...heres a link to map screen shoot
http://i.imgur.com/KkhbeUw.jpg

Comment: perhaps you should add the bootstrap tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:677px;" />
```

Comment: it's not a height issue, im showing both a height and width on body and div element..see screen shot
i.imgur.com/KkhbeUw.jpg

Comment: Have you tried it? I actually encountered the same issue  and quit using  bootstrap tabs and my project changed to not implemen using  tabs after all. So I did not push thru with fixing this bug. Good luck i'm starring this post for future reference,

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this one out.

You have to initialize your map after the tab is shown.

For me, this worked:

```
var map;
$('a[data-toggle="tab"][href="#maptab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    if (map == undefined) {
        // initialize map code here
        map = new google.maps.Map(...);
    }
});
```

Of course set your tab ID properly.